# Creating network bridge sometimes (but not always) fails with error "an unexpected error occurred while configuring the network bridge"

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, bridge, usb-network-adapter

I am currently trying to set up multiple identical systems. All are using WIndows 10 LTSC 2019 as operating system, and have three Intel I210 NICs installed. What I am trying to do is to manually bridge two of the three adapters and create a network bridge. What I have observed is that sometimes (I would say in 30 to 50 percent of my tries), this operation fails with an error message: "an unexpected error occurred while configuring the network bridge"

Here are some more details what I am actually doing:

1.) Open ncpa.cpl

[image: Network adapters overview]

2.) Select the two devices that I wish to bridge by pressing the Ctrl-key, and then selecting both Ethernet adapters

3.) rightclick one of the two selected adapters and select "Bridge Connections" from the context menu
[image: Bridge connections context menu]

4a.) At this point, the operation is either successful (50-70 percent of all tries), and when I look at the properties of my bridge it looks like this:

[image: Properties of successful network bridge]

4b.) When the operation fails (30-50 percent of all cases), the following error message appears, and the bridge is generated, but only one of the adapters (usually the adapter that was under the mouse of the two selected adapters when right-clicking) is present in the properties, the other adapter is missing

[image: Error message]

[image: Properties of unsuccessful network bridge]

I can repeat this process over and over again deleting the bridge afterwards and performing the exact steps again, and as stated above, the success rate will be around 50-70 percent. I have multiple identical systems of this type, so I can say it is no hardware failure. Of course I have tried updating the Intel NIC drives and tried various versions, but all driver versions show the same behaviour.

It looks like this behaviour is totally coincidental, and I would simply like to know why this is happening.

Any hints would be very appreciated. Thank you!